# Is there a faster way to loop through this code?

Tags: python

I have a long list of generated names, and a 5000 word file containing acceptable names. I want to find the names in my list that also appear on the file. How do I do this?

I've tried using a loop, but that takes too long for what I need, because my file of names is too long to search through the whole file for each generated name. When n is 12 numbers long, there are 531441 names in my generated list.

Here is some code:

```py
from time import process_time
from itertools import product
start = process_time()
n = "5747867437"
phone = {2: ["A", "B", "C"], 3: ["D", "E", "F"], 4: {"G", "H", "I"}, 5: ["J", "K", "L"], 6: ["M", "N", "O"], 7: ["P", "R", "S"], 8: ["T", "U", "V"], 9: ["W", "X", "Y"]}
li = set(open("dict.txt", "r").read().strip().split("\n"))
num = []
names = []
for x in n:
    num.append(phone[int(x)])
for y in product(*num):
    names.append(''.join(y))
available = []
ad = False
for z in names:
    if z in li:
        available.append(z)
acceptable.sort()
print(acceptable)
if acceptable:
    for a in acceptable:
        print(a + "\n")
else:
    print("NONE\n")
print(process_time() - start)
```

The file "acceptable_names.txt" is the file with the acceptable names in it.
Right now it takes 3 seconds. Is there a way to make this faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry in advance if my code or language is confusing. I haven't learned python for a very long time yet, and this is my first post on SO.

Comment: Make a set of the list of names and a set of the names in the file then get the intersection.

Comment: `for x in n:` produces `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` with `n = 5747867437` - please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `li` is never used ... but given two different "contents" ... there are more things quirky in your code - f.e. `product` not being specified. Please fix and provide a [mre]

Comment: @wwii That works. Thanks! Again, sorry about my lack of python knowledge. Also, I fixed n now, to a string. It shouldn't have an error message anymore.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above, use the intersection between sets. Something like:

```
set_names = set(names)
set_li = set(li)
acceptable = set_names.intersection(set_li)

# if you want to sort it, convert it into a list first
print(list(acceptable).sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

use sets https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

finding in list O(n) 
finding in set O(1)

```
# converting list to set
names = set(names)
for z in li:
    if z in names:
        acceptable.append(z)
acceptable.sort()
print(acceptable)
```

Comment: If you had run this code ... you would have found plenty errors... - starting with `for x in n:`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested - use sets. Trim what is not needed from your code. MRE of what your code could look like:

```
from itertools import product

def writeAcceptFile(filename):
    with open(filename,"w") as f:
        f.write("JIM\nJON\nTIM\nIKE")

def getNamesFromFile(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return set(name.strip() for name in f.readlines())


fn = "acceptable_names.txt" 
writeAcceptFile(fn)
accept = getNamesFromFile(fn)

phone = {2: ["A", "B", "C"], 3: ["D", "E", "F"], 4: {"G", "H", "I"}, 
         5: ["J", "K", "L"], 6: ["M", "N", "O"], 7: ["P", "R", "S"], 
         8: ["T", "U", "V"], 9: ["W", "X", "Y"]}

n = 566

ok = [k for k in ( ''.join(l) 
                  for l in product(*(phone[int(x)] 
                                     for x in str(n)))) 
      if k in accept]

print(ok) # ['JON']
```

Instead of a "silly" oneliner you can do it using lists and loops:

```
# or by foot:
names = []
num = []
for x in str(n):
    num.append(phone[int(x)])
for y in product(*num):
    n = ''.join(y)
    # only add name if in accepted list
    if n in accept:
        names.append(''.join(y))

print(names)  # ['JON']
```

The reason to use sets is that they are extremly fast (i.e. constant time, irrespectable of how many things are in them) for *contains* checks.

Your code loops for each of your generated words (531441) over the whole list (5k) of allowed words - making it slow.